# Rails: how to list all accessible attributes of an ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say that I have a data model called `Widget`.  If I pick one widget...

```
widget = Widget.find(1)
```

... then I can get its attributes with `widget.attributes.keys`.

But what if I don't want to find a Widget?

Is there a way to list all the attributes of the Widget class (which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`) without having to retrieve one particular Widget first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get attributes directly from data model:

```
Widget.column_names
```

Comment: A little fixation. It's not work with `password` and `password_confirmation` attributes if you're using `has_secure_password`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need "accessible attributes", meaning attributes marked as accessible with `attr_accessible`, then you can use [`Widget.accessible_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/accessible_attributes).